# How do I use Groovy to construct and return a new object, using other objects sourced from a 3rd party application?

Tags: groovy, rjava, groovyshell

How do I use Groovy to construct and return a new object, using other objects sourced from a 3rd party application?

Basically, I am trying to use Groovy to construct an object of type C. I am pushing A and B objects into the JVM via 
R (the rGroovy package), using the binder. How do I write do something like this using Groovy script? I must do this without writing actual Java code.

Below is an illustration of what I want to do, but in Java.

```
import com.package_one.A;
import com.package_two.B;
import com.package_three.C;

class myClass{

public  getC( A a, B b){

return new C(a,b));

}

public static void main(String[] args){

a = new A();
b = new B();

c = getC(a,b);

}

}
```

In rGroovy, so far I've been able to do something like this, with objects A and B pushed into the binder.

R side:

```
variables = list()
variables["name1"] = JavaObjectA
variables["name2"] = JavaObjectB

groovyScript = paste(

"import com.package_one.A"
"import com.package_two.B",
"import com.package_three.C",
"                          ",
"println binder.name1.toString()",
sep="\n")


Evaluate(groovyScript,variables)

Output:
"com.package.A@2f92e0f4"
```

FYI,
(I know it'd be great to just write a simple wrapper in Java and call it from R using rJava. But that's ruled out because I'm not supposed to use Java code.)